# create xslt using java

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I want to create xsl file using java. I have search on Internet and found some resources where they are using DOM to create xsl file same as we create xml file. So I want to know that is there any API to create xsl file using java?

thnx

Comment: xsl are xml files, you can use any xml capable library to build xsl, I don't know if any exist that are specifically made for creating xsl though.

Comment: This may be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501566/create-xslt-files-programmatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the Mule ESB DataMapper generate XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969243/can-the-mule-esb-datamapper-generate-xslt)